# How to remove third-party cookies in Firefox pages?

Tags: firefox, cookies

When browsing a webpage in Firefox, one can right-click on the page and click Show Page Info, and from there he can see and erase all the cookies for the site in question. However, the site in question may also use third-party cookies. How might we see which third-party cookies were sent for the current page, and how might we remove them?

Note that I am not interested in removing all the cookies in Firefox, I am only interesting in seeing and removing the third-party cookies used on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open Firefox's Web Console and view all the third-party page requests made. The information shown for each such request includes the cookies sent and received in the associated response. Firefox's usual cookie management functions can be used to delete those cookies.